# how to get filename of embedded resource of an exe?

Tags: c#

In visual studio, I have a file with build action set to 'Embedded Resource'. I would like to extract this file during runtime but I could not get the filename:

```
// returns null
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceInfo(resourceName).FileName
```

Comment: Once the resource has been embedded, _there is no file name_. Since your EXE could be run anywhere, including on a machine different from where it was compiled, what good is the file name going to do you? What is it you are really trying to do? What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am packing my app dependencies into my exe. I am avoiding installers because they might require admin rights or some machines might block it.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't answer the question I asked. Why is it that you want to obtain the original file name from the resource? If you got this file name, what would you do with it?

Comment: Once I have the filenames, I will copy the resource streams to their corresponding output filenames and put them together with the exe based on Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location. Thereafter, my app exe will be able to use the dlls, configs.

Comment: @happymeal Oh, you want to avoid installers because of blocking/permission issues... so you write an installer. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the manifest resource names *do* include the original file name and project-relative subdirectory.

The key piece of information missing from the other answer (making that answer much less than useful) is that the project name and any folder/directory in which the original file was contained are represented as components in the resource name. That whole manifest resource name is delimited into those components using the `'.'` character.

With that knowledge in hand, you should be able to correctly process your resources. In particular, you'll want to remove the first component of the name (which is just the project name), and then treat all but the last component of the name as directory names.

This is a little tricky, due to the fact that a) your file name probably has an extension (and so already has a `'.'` character in it), and b) the compiler will escape (in a rudimentary way) any `'.'` characters found in folder/subdirectory names.

Here is a code example that shows the basic approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()));
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        string exeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);

        foreach (string resourceName in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            string fileName = _GetFileNameFromResourceName(resourceName),
                directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }

            using (Stream outputStream =
                File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(exeDirectory, fileName)))
            {
                assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName).CopyTo(outputStream);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string _GetFileNameFromResourceName(string resourceName)
    {
        // NOTE: this code assumes that all of the file names have exactly one
        // extension separator (i.e. "dot"/"period" character). I.e. all file names
        // do have an extension, and no file name has more than one extension.
        // Directory names may have periods in them, as the compiler will escape these
        // by putting an underscore character after them (a single character
        // after any contiguous sequence of dots). IMPORTANT: the escaping
        // is not very sophisticated; do not create folder names with leading
        // underscores, otherwise the dot separating that folder from the previous
        // one will appear to be just an escaped dot!

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool escapeDot = false, haveExtension = false;

        for (int i = resourceName.Length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            if (resourceName[i] == '_')
            {
                escapeDot = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (resourceName[i] == '.')
            {
                if (!escapeDot)
                {
                    if (haveExtension)
                    {
                        sb.Append('\\');
                        continue;
                    }
                    haveExtension = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                escapeDot = false;
            }

            sb.Append(resourceName[i]);
        }

        string fileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(sb.ToString());

        fileName = new string(fileName.Reverse().ToArray());

        return fileName;
    }
}
```

Create a new project with the above code, and then add embedded resources to the project, in project folders or not as you like, to see the result.

**NOTE:** you may find that it's useful to filter the resource names list. For example, you'll get a resource named something like `MyProjectName.Resources.resources` if your project has traditional resources that you've added using the Designer (i.e. showing the project properties, then clicking on the "Resources" tab and adding resources there instead of explicitly as embedded resources). Otherwise, you will get literally every single manifest resource.

**NOTE:** keep in mind that to write to the directory where the executable is running from, you *might* need higher level of privileges than the current process has. E.g. if the user copies your EXE to a directory in the "Program Files" directory as admin, but then tries to run the program as a limited user. As commenter Luaan intimates above under your question, it does seem like you would be better off just implementing some sort of installer. (Visual Studio provides free access to the basic Install Shield product, or you can use e.g. WiX…it's not actually necessary to write an installer from scratch to implement an installer).

Comment: Supporting an unchecked agreement that all resource file names should have no more than one dot is worse than just keeping a dictionary with resource name as a key and a file name as a value

Comment: @astef: perhaps you missed the statement in the answer: _"Here is a code example that shows **the basic approach**"_. It is well within the norm to provide illustrative code without necessarily doing all of the OP's work for them. That hardly renders the answer "not useful". I guess you wanted something you could just copy/paste into your own program, and would be satisfied with nothing less?

Comment: The problem is that there's no way to get the real file name from resource name string. You've written the code that will work only for some special filenames and for most of internet searchers your answer is harmful.

Comment: @astef: _"for most of internet searchers your answer is harmful"_ -- really? You honestly believe that for **most** people seeking a solution, they will have file names with more than one extension, and at the same time cannot read the comment warning about that and adjust their approach to suit? That's a surprisingly large population of people, for what seems to me a vanishingly small intersection of circumstances.

Comment: I believe that your answer will be harmful, especially while it is marked as an answer. Everyone can read your comment, but still it will cost a lot of time for searchers who expect a general solution. You don't want to scroll down solutions that work only in some time zones, or for some special users, etc.

Comment: It's only harmful if one does not explain the limitations or issues and how to safely avoid them.  A gun is harmful, but with the correct knowledge the chances of issues can be significantly reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Please note GetManifestResourceInfo(resourceName).FileName only gets the name of the file that contains the manifest resource, if it is not the same as the manifest file. About manifest see here:
http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/682-what-is-manifest.aspx

You can get a list of name of all resources in an assembly using the Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames Method.

Like:

//str contains all embedded resources name

```
 string[] str = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Comment: that gives the list of embedded resources but it does not contain the filenames.